# input integer and string in one line python

Tags: python, input

How to get both int and string inputs from one input line in python
Example:
For the given line

```
10 I love coding
```

i want to get the 10 and I love coding as separate variables. I tried `input().split()` but as there is space between I and love there arises a confusion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can limit the split:

```
>>> input().split(maxsplit=1)
10 I love coding
['10', 'I love coding']

>>> a,b = input().split(maxsplit=1)
10 I love coding
>>> a
'10'
>>> b
'I love coding'
```

Comment: what if its like "I love 10 coding"?