# How to get string and int as input in one line in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, input, integer

I have seen the below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50481585/input-integer-and-string-in-one-line-python) for my answer but still didn't get an expected answer.

If I provide Name and Number in one line, Python should take the first value as a string and second as an integer.

Comment: what have you tried so far ? any example and expected output ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to input 2 integers in one line in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253863/how-to-input-2-integers-in-one-line-in-python)

Comment: @Masklinn I did't get proper solution from this one [How to input 2 integers in one line in Python?]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253863/how-to-input-2-integers-in-one-line-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a, b = [int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in input().split()]
```

It will convert to int any part of input if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
s, num = input("Give str and int :\n").split()
num = int(num)
print(s, type(s))
print(num, type(num))
```

Output :

```
Give str and int :
hello 23
hello <class 'str'>
23 <class 'int'>
```

Comment: It is not one liner.

Comment: Thanks @phoenixo, but is there any possibility without typecasting the string into integer value?

Comment: @MahendrasingJPardeshi You have to use typecasting because everything what you put in input is a string.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the input had to be "in one line", not the code

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain to have a string and a number you can use list comprehension to get the values of both.

```
x = "Hello 345"

str_value = "".join([s for s in x if s.isalpha()])  # list of alpha characters and join into one string
num_value = int("".join([n for n in x if n.isdigit()]))  # list of numbers converted into an int

print(str_value)
>> Hello

print(num_value)
>> 345
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the string and int by using regular expressions as follows:

```
import re

input_text = "string489234"

re_match = re.match("([^0-9]*) ?([0-9]*)", input_text)

if re_match:
    input_str = re_match.group(1)
    input_int = re_match.group(2)
```

see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html